# How do I map a specific website path to a servlet running on a different port with IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7, port, reverse-proxy

## The situation:

- I have a website being hosted on IIS localhost:80
- I also have a Java servlet called Metabase being hosted on localhost:3000
- Lets say my website is http://website.com

## I want users to be able to:

- visit http://website.com get the IIS website at port 80
- Visit http://website.com/metabase and get redirected internally to the servlet on port 3000

## Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. in IIS create new virtual directory `metabase`
2. setup http redirect from virtual directory `metabase` to localhost:3000
3. enabled firewall rules (if necessary)

p.s. are you sure that port 3000 is good for you? usually using ports like 81, 8000, 8080

following sample running on IIS 7.5

test: http://1click.sdk.1click.lv/test will redirect you to http://1click.sdk.1click.lv:8000/